# pod 'FBSDKLoginKit' will not install in Xcode Project

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, cocoapods

[image: This is what shows up in the terminal]

I have tried doing the `pod repo remove trunk`, `pod install`, `pod update` process, but it doesn't seem to work either. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your CocoaPods and reinstall it.
Or juste use Swift Package Manager => https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did. SPM was way easier to work with

Answer (score 1):

Seems quite a common error.
First add this string at the top of the Podfile `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`
On the terminal type `pod repo remove trunk` and then try a `pod install`

Comment: thanks! I ended up doing it via the SPM method